# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock in Azure hosted multi-container Web App

Tags: azure, docker-compose, traefik

Using Azure Web Apps for Containers to spin up a docker-compose configuration. The primary proxy is Traefik which needs access to the docker API. The container start up correctly. But the traefik container can not access the docker API socket file.

The docker-compose settings for the volume of the traefik container is:

```
    services:
       traefik:
          image: "traefik:v2.0"
          [...]
          volumes:
             - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
          [...]
```

The containers start up successfully with the following log:

> 2019-09-16 10:40:35.040 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub:
>   library/traefik:v2.0 2019-09-16 10:40:35.589 INFO  - v2.0 Pulling from
>   library/traefik 2019-09-16 10:40:35.810 INFO  -  Digest:
>   sha256:97c6da99b265de1c50e866ff66f927abb84659dcb7916c33e17623fc6969551c
>   2019-09-16 10:40:35.816 INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for
>   traefik:v2.0 2019-09-16 10:40:35.835 INFO  - Pull Image successful,
>   Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds 2019-09-16 10:40:35.871 INFO  -
>   Starting container for site 2019-09-16 10:40:35.872 INFO  - docker run
>   -d -p 40317:80 --name containertest3_traefik_1_6d1c6629 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e
>   WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=containertest3 -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e
>   WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e
>   WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=containertest3.azurewebsites.net -e
>   WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=902eae0c51eb407ec9308de2a1c3fce2b35f53f6d148e328560acba2560930f0
>   -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 traefik:v2.0 --api.insecure=true --providers.docker=true --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false --entrypoints.web.address=:80 --entryPoints.web.forwardedHeaders.insecure
>
> 2019-09-16 10:40:36.215 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub:
>   containous/whoami 2019-09-16 10:40:36.779 INFO  - latest Pulling from
>   containous/whoami 2019-09-16 10:40:36.780 INFO  -  Digest:
>   sha256:09229ae40edb92e95b15e90fef46bfadab14fd1ec2232aca717a501741fcf391
>   2019-09-16 10:40:36.788 INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for
>   containous/whoami:latest 2019-09-16 10:40:36.790 INFO  - Pull Image
>   successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds 2019-09-16
>   10:40:36.815 INFO  - Starting container for site 2019-09-16
>   10:40:36.816 INFO  - docker run -d -p 0:80 --name
>   containertest3_whoami_1_6d1c6629 -e
>   WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e
>   WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=containertest3 -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e
>   WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e
>   WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=containertest3.azurewebsites.net -e
>   WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=902eae0c51eb407ec9308de2a1c3fce2b35f53f6d148e328560acba2560930f0
>   -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 containous/whoami
>
> 2019-09-16 10:40:47.048 INFO  - Started multi-container app 2019-09-16
>   10:40:47.099 INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container
>   containertest3_traefik_1_6d1c6629 for site containertest3 2019-09-16
>   10:40:47.101 INFO  - Container containertest3_traefik_1_6d1c6629 for
>   site containertest3 initialized successfully and is ready to serve
>   requests.

However, in the error logs, Traefik can not acces the docker api and therefore does not work correctly:

> 2019-09-16T10:40:47.505909459Z time="2019-09-16T10:40:47Z" level=error
>   msg="Provider connection error Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
>   unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?, retrying
>   in 1.080381816s" providerName=docker
>
> 2019-09-16T10:40:48.585335458Z time="2019-09-16T10:40:48Z" level=error
>   msg="Failed to retrieve information of the docker client and server
>   host: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
>   unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

Final error for the Traefik container:
**"Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"**

Any idea how to fix this error in the Azure app environment? Is this not possible within the Azure hosting/preview for App containers?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Did not solve. Error stays the same. Must be related to access the docker api for traefik. see comment below your proposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Web App service does not allow for reading from docker.sock.
You need to use another configuration provider in traefik if you want to run multi-container in Azure App Service.